# VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'XStandard.MD5'

Tags: vbscript

The script work on the local computer but not remotely. Any idea?
I'm getting VBScript runtime error "ActiveX component can't create object: XStandard.MD5".

```
    strSource = "C:\WINNT"
    Set objFSO = CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strSource)
    Set colfiles = objFolder.Files

   For each file in colfiles
   Set objMD5 = CreateObject("XStandard.MD5")
```

Comment: Are you sure that XStandard is installed on the remote computer you're trying to run this on?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. As mentioned earlier; it works from the local computer, but fails remotely

Answer (score 2):

Go to the DLL folder and use in command prompt **> regsrv32 XMD35.dll**

http://www.xstandard.com/en/documentation/xmd5/

Answer (score 1):

When you want to instruct a remote computer to instantiate a given ActiveX object, you need to specify the name of the remote server when calling the `CreateObject(progID, [serverName])` function.

Otherwise, the script engine attempts to instantiate the object from the local machine.

For example:

```
Set objMD5 = CreateObject("XStandard.MD5", nameOfYourServer)
```

And of course, the component must be available on the server.

More info about [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcw63t7z%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN

Comment: Modified the code to read Set objMD5 = CreateObject("XStandard.MD5", StrComputer)

Comment: Can you instantiate other ActiveX objects? If it fails only with the XStandard.MD5 component, maybe there is a permission problem...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it has anything to do with the syntax of line 2. you are missing an open quotation. You have:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

You should have:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but google sent me here with the same problem.  In my case it was a 32-bit vs 64-bit issue - I needed to use the 32-bit version of CScript to execute.

More details here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/helloworld/archive/2007/12/12/activex-component-can-t-create-object-when-creating-a-32-com-object-in-a-64-bit-machine.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The XStandard.MD5 is a component that is NOT standard in all computers. it is something that needs to be installed. However even after installing you may still run into the same error. This may be because you are running the script in a 64bit system. for some reason the 64bit wscript won't use the xmd5.dll. however you can make a workaround by associating the scriptfiles to run on the 32bit version of wscript. by

- going into your default programs. (**Windows 8+** Right click the startbutton area [category view] Click Programs, then Default Programs then Associate a file type or protocol with a program) (**Windows 7-** click on start then click default programs)
- Then click **vbs** then click change program, change it to

  > C:\Windows\SysWow64\Wscript.exe

  **NOTE ONLY ON 64BIT**

Answer (score 0):

As dmogle says in his comment, you need to make sure that the component is installed on the remote computer. Assuming that you've got access to that computer, download the dll to it and then run the command `regsvr32 XMD5.dll` as can be seen [here](http://xstandard.com/en/documentation/xmd5/#installation).

On another note, your script looks a little funny, the twp last lines are:

```
For each file in colfiles
Set objMD5 = CreateObject("XStandard.MD5")
```

Which means that you'll be creating an instance of the MD5 object for each file. I've never used the component in question, but I'm fairly sure that you probably want to create only one instance of the object and then call the functions on that object multiple times. So I'd suggest changing the order of those lines to:

```
Set objMD5 = CreateObject("XStandard.MD5")
For each file in colfiles
```